# UWP MapControl: Web Mercator

Tags: uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

What is the math behind the actual UWP MapControl (like in Windows 10 Maps-App) with "WebMercator" projection? It seems it isn't a real static/quadratic web mercator (EPSG:3857).
It's slightly ellipsoid.

For normal web mercator you can use these [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator#Formulas) but for the UWP control it will not work.

What kind of "web mercator" is that projection and what's the math behind?

Comment: Not sure what "static" or "quadradic" are supposed to mean here. Do you perhaps mean spherical? How do you tell the difference between what you observe and what you expect, i.e. that it's "slightly ellipsoid"? For a sample implementation of web mercator, that also works with Bing Maps layers, see my [XAML Map Control](https://github.com/ClemensFischer/XAML-Map-Control).

Comment: For example just observe London, Moscow and northern Scandinavia and the relative positions of these 3 Points when you zoom in/out.

Answer (score 1):

The UWP map control doesn't work like most simple tile-based Web Mercator map controls. If you're trying to reverse-engineer the projection to overlay content yourself and have it line up, that won't work. The UWP map control uses a true 3D projection at all times. Internally it can overlay web Mercator tiles into the 3D projection using the available tile layer API's.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. The tile layer API is not enough. I need to position geometries over the map and the standard/integrated API for geometries is too slow. So, I would like to draw the geometries by myself but the positioning is a little bit difficult without knowing the math behind the control.

Comment: If you're working with points/lines/polygons, Performance for large sets of vector data should be improved from Creator's update onward and will be much faster than trying to position equivalent XAML elements. There were some additional performance improvements for lines in Fall creator's update. Any XAML item will also never be perfectly in sync with the map as layout and rendering happen on two different threads.

Comment: I will give it a try. I only made experiences with drawing with the UWP control before Fall Creators Update. But also before that Update the web mercator in UWP control was a real web mercator and everything was fine. They changed the projection with that update.
I remember that in Windows 8 map control there was a "shape layer" where drawing geometries was extremely performant. Hope this will come back.

Comment: I made a little test showing a rectangle at the pointer position using PointerMoved event. [Adding a MapPolygon to MapElements and changing/updating the GeoPath] It's very laggy. :(

Comment: If you want to update polygon path geometry dynamically, that will be a bit slower than points or lines. Calling TryOffsetToLocation is also not a cheap call if that's what your test was doing to get map Lat/Longs from screen points. A quick test like this looks OK on a mid-range machine - it's not updating at 60FPS, but it follows the mouse cursor reasonably. The MapElements are definitely optimized for geometry that isn't updated dynamically as that's the primary use case. Most map control users have large sets of geo data that are added once and don't move.

Comment: The OffsetToLocation method isn't really the problem. I made a test with 1,000,000 random points on an i5 4670k 4.2GHz machine. It took approx 5-6 seconds. So, for a rectangle with 4 points it's not the critical method. The updating of the GeoPath results on my machine at approx 10 to 15 fps. That's the critical "point" here, I guess. The updating results in a complete recalculation and it seems that this computation is basically relatively expensive independent from the number of points.
 1/2

Comment: You're right when saying that for the most cases a dynamically changing is not needed instead of an initial set of a lot of points/locations.
I also guess that there could be an issue with the "new" all-time 3D projection. With classic web mercator the computation seems much more easier/faster. 2/2

Comment: One question: What ist the difference of Win 8 MapControl ShapeLayer and Win 10 MapControl MapElements? Why was the old ShapeLayer so much more performant?

Comment: The Windows 8 Map Control was a simple tile-based raster map control - it had no 3D projection, rotation/tilt, dynamic labeling, custom styling, etc. Since it was just a flat bitmap, the projection math for user shapes was a lot simpler

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Comment: The answers were very helpful, but they didn't answer the original question. The question for the math behind the control/projection is still open.